# Change drawing order of multiple CAShapeLayers

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, native

I have my program drawing several different CGMutablePaths, each of which belongs to its own CAShapeLayer. [It currently looks like this](http://i68.tinypic.com/15878qp.png)

Notice how the lines of the rectangle overlap the circles. [Here is how I want it to look](http://i68.tinypic.com/6zlw5j.png)

Essentially, I want the ellipses and their fill to be drawn on top of the lines of the rectangle.

In my code, I have an array of CAShapeLayers, the first of which is the rectangle. In awakeFromNib(), I loop through all the shape layers and update information like the stroke width and fill, then I manually change the fill color of the rectangle to be different. In the draw function, I create all my paths, rectangle first, then ellipses. Finally, I add those paths to their relative shape layer, ellipses after the rectangle.

I have tried swapping the order in each case, but no luck. I honestly can't think of anything else that might be effecting draw order. The strangest part about it is that, in the first image, you'll see that the bottom left ellipse has indeed been drawn above the rectangle, but nowhere in my code is it set apart.

```
var shapeLayers: [String: CAShapeLayer] = [
    "rectangle": CAShapeLayer(),
    "ellipse1": CAShapeLayer(),
    "ellipse2": CAShapeLayer()...and so on
]

override func awakeFromNib() {
    wantsLayer = true

    for (_, shapeLayer) in shapeLayers {
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ColorScheme.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = ColorScheme.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.path = nil
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare
        layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    shapeLayers["rectangle"]?.fillColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
}

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let rectangle = CGMutablePath().addRect(selectionBounds)
    let ellipse1 = CGMutablePath().addEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: somePoint, size: someSize))
    let ellipse2 = CGMutablePath().addEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: somePoint, size: someSize))
    ...and so on

    shapeLayers["rectangle"]?.path = rectangle
    shapeLayers["ellipse1"]?.path = ellipse1
    shapeLayers["ellipse2"]?.path = ellipse2...and so on
}
```

I'm clearly missing something basic in my understanding of shapeLayers and paths. Your help is greatly appreciated - TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) to force the layers to draw in a specific order.  Just assign them arbitrary values as long as the numbers ascend from back layer to front layer.

Comment: added a count variable to awakeFromNib and incremented it in the for loop: shapeLayer.zPosition = CGFloat(count) and it didn't change anything. However, when I add shapeLayers["bounds"]?.zPosition = -1 after everything, it works.